# AJAX | Using alert(); function in the other file doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on Ajax and still learning to use it properly. I'm wondering why in one side of Ajax alert(); works but on the other side - no.

It's pretty basic code:

```
$('.naudoti_papildus_visiems').click(function() {
    var n;                  

    $.post('/ajax/naudoti_papildus_visiems.php', { status : 1, fermos_id : '<?php echo $id_kurat; ?>', gyvulio_tipas : '<?php echo $type_zagon; ?>' },
    function(data) {
        var typeclick = data.typeclick,
            typeu = data.typeu,
            stil = data.stil,
            stildell = data.stildell;

        $.noty.closeAll();
        if (n) {
            n.setText('<b>' + data.message + '</b>');
            n.setType(typeu);
        } else {
            n = noty({
                text: '<b>' + data.message + '</b>',

                type: typeu,
                dismissQueue: false,
                layout: 'top',
                theme: 'defaultTheme',
                timeout: 3000,
            });
        }
    }, 'json');
});
```

"naudoti_papildus_visiems.php" content:

```
<script>alert(9);</script>
```

I've tested one thing: using alert(); function inside an Ajax, it works:

```
$('.naudoti_papildus_visiems').click(function() {
var n;                  

$.post('/ajax/naudoti_papildus_visiems.php', { status : 1, fermos_id : '<?php echo $id_kurat; ?>', gyvulio_tipas : '<?php echo $type_zagon; ?>' },
function(data) {
    var typeclick = data.typeclick,
        typeu = data.typeu,
        stil = data.stil,
        stildell = data.stildell;

    alert(9); // works

    $.noty.closeAll();
    if (n) {
        n.setText('<b>' + data.message + '</b>');
        n.setType(typeu);
    } else {
        n = noty({
            text: '<b>' + data.message + '</b>',

            type: typeu,
            dismissQueue: false,
            layout: 'top',
            theme: 'defaultTheme',
            timeout: 3000,
        });
    }
}, 'json');
});
```

Chrome console doesn't show any errors. Any help would be appreciated.

`loelsonk:` still doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
    $('.naudoti_papildus_visiems').click(function() {
    var n;                  

$.ajax({
  url: '/ajax/naudoti_papildus_visiems.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType : 'json',
  data: { status : 1, fermos_id : '<?php echo $id_kurat; ?>', gyvulio_tipas : '<?php echo $type_zagon; ?>' },
  success: function(data) {
        var typeclick = data.typeclick,
            typeu = data.typeu,
            stil = data.stil,
            stildell = data.stildell;

        $.noty.closeAll();
        if (n) {
            n.setText('<b>' + data.message + '</b>');
            n.setType(typeu);
        } else {
            n = noty({
                text: '<b>' + data.message + '</b>',

                type: typeu,
                dismissQueue: false,
                layout: 'top',
                theme: 'defaultTheme',
                timeout: 3000,
            });
        }

        $('#data').html(data);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: check your console for error.

Comment: Ajax won't execute any code your fetching

Comment: @urfusion no error.
*Endless what do you mean?

Comment: I mean by Javascript errors which you can check in your browser console.

Comment: where is your second alert? in the php?

Comment: Your ajax success is receiving `data` which it then manipulates.  It's not returning html that it "runs", it's just data, in this case it's just a plain string.  Your best bet is to return json containing information eg, `{ alert: "9" }` then handle it in your js, eg something like `if (data.alert) alert(data.alert));`

Comment: @Edwin yes, in the "naudoti_papildus_visiems.php" file.

Comment: @freedomn-m can you explain more, please? Should I create another .json file only for the alert()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to execute js code you mentioned `<script>alert(9);</script>` from your request response append it to a `#temp` container.

First create `#temp` container we append response:

```
<div id="temp"></div>
```

Instead of `$.post` we use `$.ajax`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/ajax/naudoti_papildus_visiems.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { status : 1, fermos_id : '<?php echo $id_kurat; ?>', gyvulio_tipas : '<?php echo $type_zagon; ?>' },
  success: function(response) {
    // Do whatever you want here

    // response contains js code to be executed
    // Now your code gets executed
    $('#temp').html(response);
  }
})
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here is small working example to show you how it works:

We have two files:

file 1: **index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                padding-left: 250px;
            }
            #temp {
                border: 2px solid #000;
                padding: 20px;
                width: 300px;
                min-height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
  </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Ajax</h1>
            <button id="button" type="button">Perform ajax</button>

            <div id="temp"></div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $('#button').click(function(e) {
                $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax/naudoti_papildus_visiems.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { status : 1, fermos_id : 888, gyvulio_tipas : 'some_type' },
                success: function(response) {
                    // Do whatever you want here

                    // response contains js code to be executed
                    // Now your code gets executed
                    $('#temp').html(response);
                }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

file 2: **/ajax/naudoti_papildus_visiems.php** (file is inside `ajax` dir)

```
<?php

echo 'test';
echo '<script>alert(9);</script>';
```

See how it works:

[image]

Comment: Why I should use `$.ajax`? `$.post` is much faster

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis `$.ajax` has more functionality than `$.post`. `$.ajax` syntax is more clear for me at least.

Comment: Still doesn't work :( No errors in the console. I'll update my question soon.

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis No response in you `request`? Then check your `php` file for errors. Your php file should have `echo '<script>alert(9);</script>'`.

Comment: my php file contains only 1 line of code and it's not php: `<script>alert(9);</script>`

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis then it is wrong, you should have `echo '<script>alert(9);</script>'`. Again I ask you, what is your request response. No data in your response?

Comment: still doesn't work: `<?php echo '<script>alert(9);</script>'; ?>`

Comment: It doesn't show any errors and yes, no response at all.

Comment: `$.post` is *not* faster than `$.ajax` - `.post` it's a wrapper for `.ajax` (this is directly from the query source:  `return jQuery.ajax(` ) - so in-fact reduces functionality while providing a "simpler" (debatable) interface (and is *marginally slower* as it calls `.isFunction` first).

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis I have updated my answer. See how should it working. I even added a GIF for you.